# When navigating a 2D array, check neighboring elements for valid path relative to point of entry?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

**The nature of this problem has changed since submission, but the question isn't fit for deletion. I've answered the problem below and marked it as a community post.**

I'm writing a recursive path-navigating function and the final piece I need involves knowing which cell you came from, and determining where to go next.

### The Stage

You are given a 2d array where `0's` denote an invalid path and `1's` denote a valid path. As far as I know, you are allowed to manipulate the data of the array you're navigating, so I mark a traveled path with `2's`.

### The Goal

You need to *recursively* find and print all paths from `origin` to `exit`. There are four mazes, some with multiple paths, dead ends, or loops.

I've written code that can correctly handle all three cases, except the method for finding the next path is flawed in that it starts at a fixed location relative to your current index, and checks for a travelled path; If you encounter it, it's supposed to retreat.

While this works in most cases, it fails in a case when the first place it checks happens to be the place you came from. At this point, it returns out and ends prematurely.

Because of this, I need to find a way to intelligently start scanning (clockwise or anti-clockwise) based on where you came from, so that that place is always the *last* place checked.

Here is some code describing the process (note: edge cases are handled prior to this, so we don't need to worry about that):

```
private static void main()
{
    int StartX = ;//Any arbitrary X
    int StartY = ;//Any arbitrary Y
    String Path = ""; //Recursive calls will tack on their location to this and print only when an exit path is found.
    int[][] myArray = ;//We are given this array, I just edit it as I go
    Navigator(StartX, StartY, Path, myArray);
}

private static void Navigator(int locX, int locY, String Path, int[][] myArray)
{
    int newX = 0; int newY = 0;
    Path = Path.concat("["+locX+","+locY+"]");

//Case 1: You're on the edge of the maze
    boolean bIsOnEdge = (locX == 0 || locX == myArray.length-1 || locY == 0 || locY == myArray[0].length-1);
    if (bIsOnEdge)
    {
        System.out.println(Path);
        return;
    }

    int[][] Surroundings = surroundingsFinder(locX, locY, myArray);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
//Case 2: Path encountered
        if (Surroundings[0][i] == 1) 
        {
            myArray[locX][locY] = 2;
            newX = Surroundings[1][i];
            newY = Surroundings[2][i];
            Navigator(newX, newY, myArray, Path);
        }

//Case 3: Breadcrumb encountered
        if (Surroundings[0][i] == 2)
        {
            myArray[locX][locY] = 1;
            return;
        }
    }
}

//generates 2D array of your surroundings clockwise from N to NW
//THIS IS THE PART THAT NEEDS TO BE IMPROVED, It always starts at A.
//
//  H A B
//  G - C
//  F E D
//
static int[][] surroundingsFinder(int locX, int locY, int[][] myArray)
{
    int[][] Surroundings = new int[3][8];
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {

        }
    }

    //Can be done simpler, is done this way for clarity
    int xA = locX-1; int yA = locY; int valA = myArray[xA][yA];
    int xB = locX-1; int yB = locY+1; int valB = myArray[xB][yB];
    int xC = locX; int yC = locY+1; int valC = myArray[xC][yC];
    int xD = locX+1; int yD = locY+1; int valD = myArray[xD][yD];
    int xE = locX+1; int yE = locY; int valE = myArray[xE][yE];
    int xF = locX+1; int yF = locY-1; int valF = myArray[xF][yF];
    int xG = locX; int yG = locY-1; int valG = myArray[xG][yG];
    int xH = locX-1; int yH = locY-1; int valH = myArray[xH][yH];

    int[][] Surroundings = new int[3][8];
    Surroundings[0][0] = valA; Surroundings[1][0] = xA; Surroundings[2][0] = yA;
    Surroundings[0][1] = valB; Surroundings[1][1] = xB; Surroundings[2][1] = yB;
    Surroundings[0][2] = valC; Surroundings[1][2] = xC; Surroundings[2][2] = yC;
    Surroundings[0][3] = valD; Surroundings[1][3] = xD; Surroundings[2][3] = yD;
    Surroundings[0][4] = valE; Surroundings[1][4] = xE; Surroundings[2][4] = yE;
    Surroundings[0][5] = valF; Surroundings[1][5] = xF; Surroundings[2][5] = yF;
    Surroundings[0][6] = valG; Surroundings[1][6] = xG; Surroundings[2][6] = yG;
    Surroundings[0][7] = valH; Surroundings[1][7] = xH; Surroundings[2][7] = yH;

    return Surroundings;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? As you can see, `surroundingsFinder` always finds `A` first, then `B` all the way to `H`. This is fine if and *only* if you entered from `H`. But if fails on cases where you entered from `A`, so I need to make a way to intelligently determine where to `start` finding. Once I know this, I can probably adapt the logic so I no longer use a 2D array of values, as well. But so far I can't come up with the logic for the smart searcher!

**NOTE**: I am aware that Java does not optimize middle-recursion. It seems impossible to get tail recursion working for a problem like this.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is because you're using primitive type `int` for your 2D array. Try using `Integer` objects; hopefully your Java version supports autoboxing. *Just a hunch guess, need to verify.*

Comment: No, ignore that please. Arrays are objects, so they are passed by reference. So that's not the problem.

Comment: Yeah, arrays do a shallow copy and `Integer` autoboxes `int`. But the multiple For loops involved in intelligently iterating around is too complex for me to formulate on my own.

Comment: Sorry my first comment is wrong. You *can* modify arrays in a method and it will reflect to the caller. So you're fine using the primitive `int`. Anyway I think found the problem. I'll write up an answer. Hold on.

Comment: I've posted my answer. Please take a look! I found that your recursion is incorrect as it prematurely returns when hitting a visited path, but instead it should continue looking for an unvisited path and only return when none were found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Solution

The initial goal was to print, from start to end, all of the paths that exit the array.

An earlier rendition of the script wrote "0" on treaded locations rather than "2", but for some reason I imagined that I needed the "2" and I needed to differentiate between "treaded path" and "invalid path".

In fact, due to the recursive nature of the problem, I discovered that you can in fact solve the problem writing only 0's as you go. Also, I no longer needed to keep track of where I came from and instead of checking clockwise over a matrix, I was iterating from left to right down the 3x3 matrix surrounding me, skipping my own cell.

Here is the completed code for such a solution. It prints to console upon finding an exit (edge) and otherwise traces itself around the maze, complete with recursion. To start the function, you are given a *square* 2D array of `0's` and `1's` where `1` is a valid path and `0` is invalid. You are also given a set of coordinates where you are "dropped in" (`locX`, `locY`) and an empty string that accumulates coordinates, forming a path that is later printed out (`String Path = ""`)

Here is the code:

```
static void Navigator(int locX, int locY, int[][] myArray, String Path)
{
    int newX = 0;
    int newY = 0;

    Path = Path.concat("["+locX+","+locY+"]");

    if ((locX == 0 || locX == myArray.length-1 || locY == 0 || locY == myArray[0].length-1))
    {//Edge Found
        System.out.println(Path);
        pathCnt++;
        myArray[locX][locY] = 1;
        return;
    }

    for (int row = -1; row <= 1; row++)
    {            
        for (int col = -1; col <= 1; col++)
        {
            if (!(col == 0 && row == 0) && (myArray[locX+row][locY+col] == 1))
            {   //Valid Path Found
                myArray[locX][locY] = 0;
                Navigator(locX+row, locY+col, myArray, Path);
            }
        }
    }

    //Dead End Found
    myArray[locX][locY] = 1;
    return;
}       System.out.println(Path);
        pathCnt++;
        swamp[locX][locY] = 1;
        return;
    }

    for (int row = -1; row <= 1; row++)
    {            
        for (int col = -1; col <= 1; col++)
        {
            if (!(col == 0 && row == 0) && (swamp[locX+row][locY+col] == 1))
            {   //Valid Path Found
                swamp[locX][locY] = 0;
                Navigator(locX+row, locY+col, swamp, Path);
            }
        }
    }

    //Dead End Found
    swamp[locX][locY] = 1;
    return;
}
```

As you may determine yourself, every time we "enter" a cell, we have 8 neighbors to check for validity. First, to save on run time and to avoid going out of the array during our for loop (it can't find `myArray[i][j]` if `i` or `j` point it outside, and it will error out), we check for edges. Since we're given the area of our swamp we use a truth comparison statement that essentially says (`"(am I on the top or left edge?) or (am I on the bottom or right edge?)"`). If we ARE on an edge, we print out the Path we're holding (thanks to `deep copy`, we have a unique copy of the original `Path` that only prints if we're on an edge, and includes our full set of coordinates).

If we aren't on an edge, then we start looking around us. We start at top left and move horizontally to bottom right, with a special check to make sure we're not checking where we're standing.:

```
A B C
D . E
F G H
```

This loop checks only for `1's` and only calls the function up again should that happen. Why? Because it is the second-to-last case. There is only one extra situation that will occur, and if we reach the end of the function it means we hit that case. Why write extra code (checking for `0's` to specifically recognize it?

So, as I just mentioned, if we exit the `for` loop, it means we didn't encounter any 1's at all. It means we're surrounded by zeros! It means we've hit a dead end, and that means that all we have to do is error our away out of that instance of the function, ergo the final `return;`.

All in all, the final function is simple. But coming from no background and having to realize the patterns and meanings of these cases, and after several failed attempts at this, it can take quite a bit of work. I was several days at work on perfecting this.

Happy coding, Everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be with:

```
if (Surroundings[0][i] == 2)
{
    myArray[locX][locY] = 1;
    return;
}
```

Perhaps this should be changed to:

```
if (Surroundings[0][i] == 2)
{
    // not sure why you need this if it's already 1
    myArray[locX][locY] = 1;

    // go to next iteration of the "i" loop
    // and keep looking for next available path
    continue;
}
```

Your recursive method will automatically return when none of the surrounding cells satisfy the condition `if (Surroundings[0][i] == 1)`.

**PS:** It's conventional to name your variables using small letter as the first character. For example: `surroundings`, `path`, `startX` or `myVar`

Comment: Thanks for your help, ADTC. Unfortunately, the issue became superfluous as I realized something I'd missed before in my problem and the final solution faces none of these issues. I'm submitting my own answer for posterity and marking as a community post.